# The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists (Spring MVC)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My dispatcher servlet dont working correctly. Its only starting index.jsp file, thats all, Request mapping doesn`t working.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

  <display-name>spring-cource-mvc</display-name>

  <absolute-ordering/>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="ua.ilya.springcourse" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <bean id = "viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String sayHello() {
        return "hello_world";
    }
}
```

Watched many themes and courses about this, but everywhere everything working properly.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're using the outdated configuration style instead of using Spring Boot?

Comment: A lot of projects will have and quite a few interview questions will mention XML configuration and MVC flow rather than Spring Boot afaik.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you trying to trigger URL on `localhost:8080/appname/hello`?
2. Do you have jsp page called hello_world in your view folder?
3. Is your controller located in `ua.ilya.springcourse.controller` or any subdirectory of `ua.ilya.springcourse`?
4. Are you using Eclipse as an IDE and do you by any chance have WebContent folder in your project?

The reason for the 4th question is because eclipse changed dynamic project structure, so if your eclipse is creating a dynamic web project with webapp, that means that you cannot have WebContent instead of it, you must follow the new pattern and look at webapp folder as replacement for WebContent.
You can test webapp/WebContent by creating a new Dynamic Web Project. If that is the case, just move your WEB-INF folder into webapp folder, and that's about it.
Here is also a picture of the project structure if your Eclipse is creating WebContent ( left ) or is creating webapp ( right ).
[image]

Comment: 1. No, im using "/test", in case that in my Tomcat "Application context" is "test".
2. Yes, it is in dir "view", file "hello_world.jsp"
3. No, my controller path is "ua.ilya.springcourse.HelloController.java"
4. I`m using Intellij idea ultimate

Comment: You do not have anything mapped with /test in your controller from what I can see in the code that you shared.